# Converting a level string to an array in a completely different format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I need to convert

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,]
```

To

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],]
```

I am still very new at Javascript, and I am trying to work on a level editor for a game that I am modifying. I can't change the way that either the level editor or the actual game loads levels, so my only option is to convert the formats. I am really bad at explaining my code, but the level is loaded in-game using "level[x][y]", with blocks being represented by numbers in an array. I have been working on this for several days, so any help would be appreciated. The width of the level will vary, being at least 20, but the height will always be 15. Both levels start at (0,0). Thank you for your time.

UPDATE:
I need to do something like this:

Convert
'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9' to
[['1','4','7',],['2','5','8'],['3','6','9']]

(Obviously it would be bigger than this)
I can also access the width of the level and use that in the code, and the height will always be 15.

UPDATE:
I figured it out. Thank you all so much for your help. Here is the code:

```js
function parseLvlObj(lvlObj) {
 lvl = lvlObj.level.split(',');
 lvlHeight = lvlObj.levelheight;
 lvlWidth = lvlObj.levelwidth;
 done1 = [];
 var i,j,temparray,chunk = lvlObj.levelwidth;
 k = 0;
 for (i=0,j=lvl.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
  temparray = lvl.slice(i,i+chunk);
  done1[k] = temparray;
  k = k + 1;
 }
 done = [];
 done1.pop();
 i = 0;
 j = 0;
 while (i < lvlObj.levelwidth) {
  done[i] = [];
  while (j < lvlObj.levelheight) {
   done[i][j] = done1[j].pop();
   j = j + 1;
  }
  i = i + 1;
  j = 0;
 }
 lvlObj.level = done;
 return lvlObj;
}
level = {"level":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,","levelwidth":20,"levelheight":15,"exitX":100,"exitY":100};
console.log(parseLvlObj(level))
```

Comment: Using chunk\slice will result in the array being either the wrong size, or (for lack of a better term) "turned" sideways when loaded into the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split`, `splice` and `Array.from` will simplify.

```js
const chunks = (str, size) => {
  const arr = str.split(",");
  return Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(arr.length / size) }, (_, i) =>
    arr.slice(i * size, (i + 1) * size)
  );
};

const str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
console.log(chunks(str, 3));
console.log(chunks(str, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is commonly called Chunking. Unfortunately there isn't a clean chunker in Javascript (right now). I've created a simple one, below to show how this is done.

```js
var level = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, ]

function chunk(arrayInput, chunkSize) {
  var outArray = []
  while (arrayInput.length) {
    outArray.push(arrayInput.splice(0, chunkSize))
  }
  return outArray;
}

var chunkedLevel = chunk(level,30);
console.log(chunkedLevel)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method doing something like this:

```
Array.prototype.chunk = function (chunkSize) {
  const chunkedArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i += chunkSize) {
    chunkedArray.push(this.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
  }
  return chunkedArray;
};
```

Now you just have to use `chunk()` on your original array:

```
const string = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
// Remove whitespaces and split on each ','
const array = string.replace(/ /g, '').split(',');
const chunked = array.chunk(2);
console.log(chunked);
// [ [ 0, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5 ], [ 6, 7 ] ]
```